# SCSS modules not loading in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, css-modules

I'm not sure what the problem is, as I've done this numerous times with no issues, so I'm thinking I messed something up. I'll show the Product.js component, and the module file, and please let me know if there's anything else I'm missing (for example, there's no next.config.js file either).

Thanks in advance!

Product.js

```
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core'
import styles from '../styles/Products.module.scss'

export default function Product({ product }) {
  console.log(product)
  return(
    <Card className="product">
      <img src={product.main_image} />
      {product.name && product.name}
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Products.module.scss file

```
.product {
  max-width: 300px;

  & img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

when using CSS module you should pass to `className` your `styles` object, and accessing the desired class:

```
import { Card } from '@material-ui/core'
import styles from '../styles/Products.module.scss'

export default function Product({ product }) {
  console.log(product)
  return(
    <Card className={styles.product}>
      <img src={product.main_image} />
      {product.name && product.name}
    </Card>
  )
}
```

this because CSS Module will generate an unique class name. Its class name won't be `product`, but something like `[filename]\_[classname]\_\_[hash]` (with a unique hash) to avoid name collision.

[adding CSS module](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Comment: Oh my gosh. How did I miss that!? Jeez, is it really that late for my brain? Thanks a million!

Comment: you are welcome :) it happens to all of us, hehehe. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

For anyone coming across this thread using Next.js 13 with Turbopack like I did, [SCSS/Sass is not currently supported out of the box with Turbopack](https://turbo.build/pack/docs/features/css#scss-and-less). Go into your package.json and remove `--turbo` from the line with your dev script until we get that functionality within Turbopack or a plugin. Or you can just deal with normal css modules, which work fine with Turbopack.

package.json (before)

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

package.json (after)

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using NextJS13 experimental with /app folder.

I was using sass modules in my application. Everything was working fine, but when I ran `npm run dev` again it stopped working. I also saw the same issue on GitHub but there were no solutions. I didn't find the way how to fix this, so I create application again from scratch and it started working fine.

A possible solution could be importing styles directly to `layout.tsx` not to `page.tsx`
For example:

(layout.tsx)

```
// Global application styles

import './reset.scss'
import './global.scss'

// fonts
import { inter } from './fonts'

// Import Layout components
import Navigation from "./Navigation"
import ToolboxLayout from './(toolbox)/layout'
import Toolbox from './(toolbox)/page'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      className={inter.className}
    >
      <head />
      <body className='body'>
        <Navigation />
        <main className='main'>
          <ToolboxLayout>
            <Toolbox/>
          </ToolboxLayout>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

(Navigation.tsx)

```
import styles from './Navigation.module.scss'



export default function Navigation () {
    return (
      <header className={styles.navigation}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
            <div className={styles.title}>
                <p>EuroDataCube</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.right}>
            <div className={styles.buttons}>
                info
                settings
            </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    )
}
```